# $V$ vector space over number field $K$. $L/K$ finite extension. lattice $M\subset V$. Then $M\otimes_{O_K} O_L\to V\otimes_K L$ is injection

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

"$V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over number field $K$ and $L/K$ a finite extension. $M\subset V$ is a lattice. Then $M\otimes_{O_K} O_L\to V\otimes_K L$ is injection." $O_L,O_K$ are the number rings associated to number fields $L$ and $K$ respectively.

I could think $M=O_K^n$. Then $M\otimes_{O_K}O_L=(O_L)^n$ and this embeds well into $L^n=V\otimes_KL$ by $M$ lattice in $V$. Hence injectivity of the map follows.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Can I think $M\otimes_{O_K} O_L\to V\otimes_K L$ as $M\otimes_{O_K} O_L\to V\otimes_{O_K} O_L\to V\otimes_K L$ composition? Is $(-)\otimes_{O_K}O_L$ an exact functor here?

$\textbf{Q':} $ How should I think about the last step $V\otimes_{O_K} O_L\to V\otimes_K L$ formally as tensor product. This is surely induced from $V\to V$ and $O_L\to L$ map. However I have to extend the ring of coefficients here.

Ref: Algebraic Number Theory by Taylor Frolich

Comment: I believe that $O_L$ is flat over $O_K$ as flatness is equivalent to torsion free in a Dedekind domain. Not sure I understand your second question.

Comment: It is clear that $O_K$ is a torsion free module. Every torsion free module is a direct sum of an ideal and free part. Yes. I think it follows from that. As for 2nd question, I do not know how to organize my thought process on the map as the tensors are over different rings though it has $O_L$ module structure. And should I treat this as right sided $O_L$ module map as there is no reason $O_L$ element can pass to $V$ side.?

Comment: Ah yes, there may be some subtlety in the tensor product being taken over different rings but my intuition is with your final comment